# sending publisher file using mail()

Tags: php, mysql, publisher

I have designed an email in publisher that I would like to go out via php script to new users when they register for my site. My question is how do I convert and send a publisher file via the php mail() function. Thank you

Comment: Do you want to "convert" a Microsoft Publisher file into the body of an email, or simply send the file as an attachment?

Comment: Convert the file into the body. Sorry